# ¿Cómo agrego etiquetas a líneas que he puesto en mi gráfico en r?

Tags: r, plot, label

Estoy grafiacndo una variable numérica en el tiempo y le agregué líneas a algunas fechas que me interesan, quisiera que también me especificara la fecha en que es en el gráfico, pero no consigo cómo hacerlo.

[image: gráfico ejemplo]

Este es un ejemplo de lo que hago, quiero que la línea roja indique la fecha en que es, puede ser como una etiqueta o en el eje x.

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente (h es mi data):

```
plot(as.Date(h$date), h$new.cases, type = "l")
abline(v=as.Date("2020-02-19"), col = "red")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plot(cars$speed)
abline(v=20)
text(25, 20, "abline title")
```

No he usado serie de tiempo para el ejemplo, pero el código anterior debería funcionar igualmente. Los números en la función `text` son coordenadas `(x,y)`, para encontrar una en especifico puedes usar la función `locator()` en R.

Comment: Muchas gracias @drdsdaniel, sabes si es posible hacer algo como eso sin especificar la coordenada de y?

Comment: Claro. mira la ayuda de la función `text` ahí te dirán. Pero si entiendo donde vas, puedes usar una función para especificar `y` de manera dinámica como `text(25, mean(cars$speed), "Title")`